# Is there an equivalent of the python built in function `all` in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, subset, built-in

I'm quyering a pandas dataframe `df` like this.

```
df = df[
    (df.value1 >= threshold1) &
    (df.value2 >= threshold2) &
    (df.value3.isin(list3))
    ]
```

Python has the built in function [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), which allows this syntax:

```
if all([
    value1 > threshold1,
    value2 > threshold2,
    value3 in list3,
    ]):
```

Instead of this:

```
if (
    value1 > threshold1 and
    value2 > threshold2 and
    value3 in list3,
    ):
```

Does Pandas have something similar to `all` in Python? Thanks.

Also, is this the fastest way of subsetting a Pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Comment: That really isn't the use case for `all`, and normally I would write that with `and`.

Comment: What is the use case for `all` then? Thanks.

Comment: something like `all(condition(x) for x in some_iterable)`

Comment: Note, your use of `all` does what you want, but it is not idiomatic. I would have to look at that code a couple of times before I grokked it. I would know immediately what the line using `and` is doing. Also, your use of `all`  creates an unnecessary intermediate data-structure, and uses function call. It's not efficient, and I wouldn't encourage it's use, especially if you are evaluating the condition repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! I really apprecite your comment. I understand you. I mostly use `all` and `any`, when the evaluation is not expensive. I don't like ending lines with `and` and `&` and `or`. I'll stick with the `&` line endings then. They just look ugly to me :)

Comment: I understand that! Indeed, it is against [the official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator)!

Comment: Oh, I don't like them at the beginning of a line either :D Thanks for the link to the style guide! I haven't read PEP8 in a long time! I might just delete my question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139422/discussion-between-tommy-carstensen-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 4):

[@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104309/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-python-built-in-function-all-in-pandas#comment73290345_43104309) already gave you a very good explanation about boolean indexing in Pandas.

I'd like to give you a bit nicer alternative - [DataFrame.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method:

```
df.query("value1 > @threshold1 and value2 > @threshold2 and value3 in @list3")
```

Demo:

```
In [138]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 3)),
                            columns=['value1','value2','value3'])

In [139]: df
Out[139]:
   value1  value2  value3
0       7       9       1
1       4       1       3
2       3       8       8
3       2       8       9
4       9       2       7
5       5       8       9
6       4       2       9
7       7       2       5
8       6       3       5
9       9       1       5

In [140]: threshold1 = 2

In [141]: threshold2 = 4

In [142]: list3 = [1,9]

In [143]: df.query("value1 > @threshold1 and value2 > @threshold2 and value3 in @list3")
Out[143]:
   value1  value2  value3
0       7       9       1
5       5       8       9
```